# Reduced row echelon of Z/2Z

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I've gotten (1 0 1 0 1 0; 0 1 1 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0), which looks like it is of row reduced form, but would I not also be able to simplify this further to (1 0 0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0), this is confusing me since I thought rref was unique?

Comment: The matrix after "I've gotten" is the same as that after "would I not also be able to simplify this further to". Did you mistype something?

Comment: Yes, I've corrected it now.

Comment: Could you show in question the steps how you got to the second matrix?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2
\\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+R_1
\\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+R_2
\end{align}

The RREF is unique. The matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
is not row-equivalent, because the third column is not the sum of the first and second columns like in the matrix we started with. Row-equivalence doesn't change linear relations among columns.

Comment: Could I not just add rows 1 and 2 together and get a different matrix?

Comment: @4M4D3U5M0Z4RT But it wouldn't be the RREF any longer.

Comment: is that not the same operation you used to, for example do R3 <-- R3+R1,
what I meant gives, [1 0 1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0]

Comment: @4M4D3U5M0Z4RT If you perform a nontrivial row operation on the RREF, you get a matrix which is not RREF. Anyway, you *don't* get the matrix you wish to get. It's impossible, because the matrix you'd like to reduce to is *not* row-equivalent to the given matrix.